# Android 4.2 and clock_gettime

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using these functions to measure how many milliseconds it takes to execute a function:

```
struct timespec diff_timespec(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
     struct timespec result;

     if (end.tv_nsec < start.tv_nsec)
     { 
        result.tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;        
        result.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - 1 - start.tv_sec;
     }
     else
     {
        result.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;        
        result.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
     }

    return result;
}

long long nanosec_elapsed(struct timespec diff)
{
    return ((long long)diff.tv_sec * 1000000000) + (diff.tv_nsec );
}
```

I have a function A which calls another function B. The function, A, is exposed via JNI to Java, so that it can be called from Java. The OS is Android 4.2 and the language is obviously C.

```
void functionA(void)
{
     struct timespec t1;
     struct timespec t2;
     struct timespec diff;
     long long dt;
     double delta;


     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
     functionB();
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
     diff = diff_timespec(t1,t2);
     dt = nanosec_elapsed(diff);
     delta = ((double) dt) / ((double) 1000000.0);

}


  void functionB(void)
  { 
     struct timespec t1;
     struct timespec t2;
     struct timespec diff;
     long long dt;
     double delta1;
     double delta2;
     double delta3;


     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
     /* 1. Here I do some stuff  */
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
     diff = diff_timespec(t1,t2);
     dt = nanosec_elapsed(diff);
     delta1 = ((double) dt) / ((double) 1000000.0);

     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
     /* 2. Here I do some more stuff  */
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
     diff = diff_timespec(t1,t2);
     dt = nanosec_elapsed(diff);
     delta2 = ((double) dt) / ((double) 1000000.0);

     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
     /* 3. Here I do the last stuff  */
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
     diff = diff_timespec(t1,t2);
     dt = nanosec_elapsed(diff);
     delta3 = ((double) dt) / ((double) 1000000.0);

}
```

The problem I'm having is that - *sometimes* - there's a large discrepancy between (delta1+delta2+delta3) and delta. In other words, function A reports that it takes T1 ms to execute B, and function B itself reports that it takes T2 ms...but T1 and T2 are so far apart sometimes that I'm questioning if my measurements are valid to begin with ???

Furthermore, one of the tasks that I'm measuring is sending UDP data.

According to measurements performed in the above fashion, it sometimes takes more than 5ms to send a small packet of UDP data. An extract from my log:

```
It took 9.552002 ms to send 100 bytes to server
It took 23.071289 ms to send 124 bytes to server
It took 4.791260 ms to send 128 bytes to server
It took 6.134032 ms to send 86 bytes to server
It took 10.589599 ms to send 100 bytes to server
It took 6.591797 ms to send 117 bytes to server
It took 3.173829 ms to send 117 bytes to server
```

Can anybody help me with a rational explanation for this?

Comment: One thought-  clock_gettime gets the clock time.  If the OS decides to context switch to another app (perhaps because some other app is using the network card so it can't process your request yet), it could be an unknown time before your app comes back to the forefront.  That's why profilers have clock time, system time, and user time separated out.  SO any time in the ms range is not unreasonable for, well, any function.  Especially one that has to write to the network.

Comment: So how do I measure the actual time spent on executing the code? (without wait time, sleep time, time introduced as a result of context switching etc.)

Comment: Check the man page for `clock_gettime()` to see the list of clocks.  You have `CLOCK_REALTIME` (the "wall clock" time), which can jump around when the network updates the clock on the device; `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, which doesn't jump; and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` which only advances when the thread uses the CPU.  The Dalvik "traceview" method profiling uses the last two.  There's also a separate source that's like monotonic but behaves differently when the device goes into low-power sleep.

Comment: So I should be using CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID ??